# How does a REST API URL look like without rewrites?

Tags: rest-api, ce-1.9.2.4

Magento ships a rewrite for from `/api/rest` to `api.php?type=rest`. In case I can not or don't want to use that rewrite, how would I have to change a rest URL such as `/api/rest/orders` ?

`api.php/orders?type=rest` did not work
`api.php?type=rest/orders` also not.